# One app with nodejs, different datababase per client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to create an application with nodejs in which different companies/clients connect but use different databases.

For example:

> - Application nodejs running on localhost: 3001
> - Mongo server running at localhost: 27017
> - A client (CLIENT1) accesses the nodejs application and modifies data
>     in its database -> localhost:27017/client1
> - Another client (CLIENT2) does the same and accesses the application
>     nodejs but modifies its data in localhost:27017/client2

And so on for every customer who signs up for the application.

**--------EDIT----------**

I've been testing things to get what I wanted and I think I've come up with a possible solution. The solution would be to create a connection to each database access. And when you have finished that access disconnect. I do not know if it is a good solution but I think it can be worth:

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var repository = require('./demoqueryrepository')

app.get('/createdb', function (req, res) {
    //TODO: With JWT decode get id client and pass like as param to repository
    repository.crearDemo(req.query.id, function (err, resp) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else res.send("resp");
    })
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

demomodel.js

```
 var mongo = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongo.Schema;

    module.exports = mongo.model('demodto', new Schema({
        Name: { type: String },
        Code: { type: Number },

    }));
```

demoqueryrepository.js

```
var _demo = require('./demoquerydto');
var mongo = require('mongoose')
var mongoconnect = require('./mongoconnect')

module.exports = {
    crearDemo: function (idclient, callback) {
        let newdemo = new _demo({
            Name: " Demo " + idclient,
            Code: idclient
        })
        mongoconnect.connect(idclient);
        newdemo.save(function (error) {
            if (error) callback(error, null);
            else {
                callback(null, "success");
                mongo.disconnect();
            }
        })


    }
}
```

mongoconnect.js

```
var mongo = require('mongoose')

module.exports = {
    connect: function (idclient) {
        mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/' + idclient, { useMongoClient: true }, function (err, res) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            else console.log("Connected to db")
        });
    }
}
```

when i launch requests:

localhost:3000/createdb?id=12

localhost:3000/createdb?id=13

localhost:3000/createdb?id=14

On the database server the databases are created with those id's

[image]

Comment: How you will figure out different clients by name/id? Is db schema different for different clients or similar?

Comment: The schemas are similar and the intention to identify different clients would be through an id. For example the client1 has the id 198 with which the database would be created with that name

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is make a multi-tenant nodejs application.

The approach you are taking has few disadvantages:

- There is one common database for a user-id which will tell which db to connect to and then one per client. This means you have n+1 connection.
- Your application will not scale as either you will always over provision/ under provision your databases or worse deploy changes for every new client on-boarding.

Have you considered having just one database as the schema is the same? The common fears of one client having to access data can be taken care of if you put default scope of search per client.

I had the same issue and wrote a [blog post](https://medium.com/@adhasmana/how-we-implemented-multi-tenancy-in-our-node-js-app-cf9a2515969b) about it.

Comment: I have made the decision to use a single mongo database. I read the article and you use sequelize and it would have to change a lot of things that are already implemented. So I will use a database taking care and taking into account the ids of clients. Thanks for the answer, I put it as valid, as it has made me think.